# How can I remove query string from URL?

Tags: php, xml

Here is my code. It is a simple html form with two inputs. All data is saved into xml file using DOMDocument a then all data from XML file is inserted into the table below the form. I added two buttons edit and delete (x). Now I can edit and delete any user/player from the table. And here is my problem. I need to remove query string from URL after deleting or editing. I want to add a new user/player into the table after deleting. When I delete manually query string from URL everything works fine again. But I want to delete query string automatically after deleting some user. Sorry for my English hoping you understand me. **Thanks in advance!**

```
<?php 

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

        if (is_file('database.xml')) {
            $xml->load("database.xml");
            $db = $xml->getElementsByTagName('db')->item(0);
        } else {
            $db = $xml->createElement("db");
            $xml->appendChild($db);
            $db = $xml->getElementsByTagName('db')->item(0);
        }
            $newPlayer = $xml->createElement("player");

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
                $playerStuff = $xml->createElement($key, $value);
                $newPlayer->appendChild($playerStuff); 
            }   

            $db->appendChild($newPlayer);
            $xml->save("database.xml");         
    }

$name = $number = ""; 

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
  $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
  $xml->load("database.xml");
  $player = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->item($_GET['id']);;
  $name = $player->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $number = $player->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch ($_GET['action']){
        case 'edit':
            $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
            $xml->load("database.xml");
            $player = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->item($_GET['id']);
            $nameEl = $player->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
            $numberEl = $player->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0);

                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                $newName = $xml->createElement("name", $_POST["name"]);
                $nameEl->parentNode->replaceChild($newName, $nameEl); 

                $newNumber = $xml->createElement("number", $_POST["number"]);
                $numberEl->parentNode->replaceChild($newNumber, $numberEl); 

                $db = $xml->getElementsByTagName('db')->item(0); 
                $lastElement = $db->lastChild;
                $lastElement->parentNode->removeChild($lastElement);
            }
            $xml->save("database.xml");

            break;
        case 'delete':
            $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
            $xml->load("database.xml");
            //$xml = $dokument->getElementsByTagName('xml')->item(0); 
            $player = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->item($_GET['id']);
            $player->parentNode->removeChild($player);
            $xml->save("database.xml");
            break;
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>PLAYERS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesss.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
            <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $number ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="INSERT">
        </form>
        <?php 

        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

            if (is_file('database.xml')) {

                $xml->load('database.xml');
                $players = $xml->getElementsByTagName("player");

                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr><th>" . "Player Name" . "</th><th>" . "Number". "</th></tr>";

                    foreach($players as $key => $player){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        foreach($player->childNodes as $data) {
                            echo "<td>". $data->nodeValue ."</td>";
                        }
                            echo "<td>
                                  <a href='?id={$key}&action=edit' class='buttons edit'>EDIT</a>
                                  <a href='?id={$key}&action=delete' class='buttons delete'>&#10006</a>
                                  </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
            }

            echo "</table>";

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where in your code should we focus? I can't find the word URL or QUERY in your provided code. I often use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with the custom "unparse_url()" function on that page for exploding a URL, modifying and restoring it.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, you are performing the delete/add just before rendering the page body. either redirect after doing the DB update or start using forms that "POST" your request so there is no query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say to redirect `header("Location: your-page.php");` The page you redirect to can be the same page but without the query string. It means that if someone refreshes you will not repeat the same action. So, something like this. You have to use the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) before anything is written to the page, it will not work if it is used after HTML or after something is `print` or `echo` to the page.

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch ($_GET['action']){
    case 'edit':
        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $xml->load("database.xml");
        $player = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->item($_GET['id']);
        $nameEl = $player->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
        $numberEl = $player->getElementsByTagName('number')->item(0);

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

            $newName = $xml->createElement("name", $_POST["name"]);
            $nameEl->parentNode->replaceChild($newName, $nameEl); 

            $newNumber = $xml->createElement("number", $_POST["number"]);
            $numberEl->parentNode->replaceChild($newNumber, $numberEl); 

            $db = $xml->getElementsByTagName('db')->item(0); 
            $lastElement = $db->lastChild;
            $lastElement->parentNode->removeChild($lastElement);
        }
        $xml->save("database.xml");

        break;
    case 'delete':
        $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $xml->load("database.xml");
        //$xml = $dokument->getElementsByTagName('xml')->item(0); 
        $player = $xml->getElementsByTagName('player')->item($_GET['id']);
        $player->parentNode->removeChild($player);
        $xml->save("database.xml");
        break;
    }
    header("Location: your-page.php");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help sdexp.